# C# - Folder validation

Tags: c#

```
string excludeSubFolders = "SubFolderA, SubFolderB, SubFolderC, SubFolderABC";

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(myRootFolderPath);
DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
       if (folder.Name.ToString().Trim() != "SubFolderA")
          {...}
```

A C# newbie here. Above is the code I am using to exclude "SubFolderA" which resides in my root folder (myRootFolderPath). I need to exclude all the sub-folders listed in excludeSubFolders variable.

Thank you

**UPDATE: string excludeSubFolders is being populated through a parameter outside of c# code. I just listed the output of that parameter in the format c# is expecting. Also the parameter will have "SubFolderA, SubFolderB, SubFolderC, SubFolderABC" value today while the day after tomorrow, someone will change that to "SubFolderA, SubFolderB, SubFolderC" and call the same c# code. How will this work with the presented string array suggestions?**

Comment: Regarding your update, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you MarcinJuraszek, Mo, and Phil K for your support. I combined Marcin's var with Phil's foreeach and worked perfect. I had to choose one so chose the oldest answer (sry to Mo and Phil :) ) Just out of curiosity, what adv/disadv does Marcin's var has over Mo/Phil's string[], if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change `excludeSubFolders` to be `string[]` array:

   ```
   string[] excludeSubFolders = new [] { "SubFolderA", "SubFolderB", "SubFolderC", "SubFolderABC" };
   ```
2. Use `Contains` method:

   ```
   foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
      if (!excludeSubFolders.Contains(folder.Name))
         {...}
   ```
3. To get `string[]` from single string use `String.Split()` method:

   ```
   var subFolders = input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
   ```

Comment: When does string array have .Contains? I thought it was List that has it?

Comment: @JohnOdom It's an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` and `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: What version of .NET was it added in? I'm using .NET 2.0 on this computer and I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Why the Trim()? And also the ToString() on a string?

Comment: Thank you guys...updated the OP with more detail. How does the update affect this? I don't think I will be able to pass in the whole string inside the new[] {here} right? @Steve...useless paranoia on my part? hehe

Answer (score 3):

First thing I'd do is change your `excludeSubFolders` to a string array, because that makes it much easier to work with:

```
string[] excludeSubFolders = new string[] { "SubFolderA", "SubFolderB", "SubFolderC", "SubFolderABC" };
```

then you can use LINQ to filter out the directories that match your exclusion array:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories.Where(dir => !excludeSubFolders.Contains(dir.Name.ToString().Trim())))
{
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** regarding the update to your question: if you are being handed a comma-delimited string and cannot use a string array, then you can split the string into a string array programatically:

```
string excludeSubFolders = "SubFolderA, SubFolderB, SubFolderC, SubFolderABC";
string[] excludeSubArray = excludeSubFolders.Split(new []{", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories.Where(dir => !excludeSubArray.Contains(dir.Name.ToString().Trim())))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Updated the OP. how can I still use the above logic (array...)?

Answer (score 1):

Same as Marcin's, but this changes the string to an array for you...

**Edit**: to negate any performance impact, I took the Split() out of the loop (thanks Marcin)

```
var excludeArray = excludeSubFolders.Split(new []{", "},
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
{
  if (!excludeArray.Contains(myRootFolderPath))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: And it would perform the split on every iteration.

Comment: You can inline it if you want, or assign it to a variable outside the loop if you're concerned about performance. It's better than an answer that says the question is wrong :)

Comment: Updated the OP. this seems like a good option right now as it doesn't require change of the variable type...will test it now.